# IEnumerable extension method that ingests SqlCommand and returns query results

Tags: c#, sql, generics, reflection, extension-methods

The following ingests a preexisting `SqlCommand` and returns the values.

A couple caveats right now.

1 ) Type properties must be named identical to the SQL column

2) properties must be given a custom `[SQLColumn]` attribute.

The attribute contains a `string` which I plan to use later for variation in property names while keeping column designation.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> FromCommand<T>(this IEnumerable<T> b, SqlCommand command)
    {

        using (command.Connection)
        {

            command.Connection.Open();

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {

                var readerColumns = new HashSet<string>(Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName));
                var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(o => o.IsDefined(typeof(SQLColumn)) && readerColumns.Contains(o.Name)).ToList();

                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    object OUTPUT = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

                    foreach (var item in properties)
                    {
                        item.SetValue(OUTPUT, reader[item.Name] is DBNull ? null : reader[item.Name]);
                    }

                    yield return (T)Convert.ChangeType(OUTPUT, typeof(T));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As requested, here is an example of the class utilizing the extension method.

```
public class MyType
{

    #region Properties Block

    [SQLColumn]
    public Guid GuidColumn { get; set; }

    [SQLColumn]
    public int IntColumn { get; set; }

    [SQLColumn]
    public bool BitColumn { get; set; }

    #endregion Properties Block

    #region Select Block

    [Description("Selects and returns all rows.")]
    public static IEnumerable<MyType> SelectAll()
    {

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(QueryRepository.SELECT_MyType_ALL, Conn.ConnectionString) { CommandTimeout = 0 };

        return new List<MyType>().FromCommand(command);

    }

    [Description("Selects and returns rows filtered by GuidColumn.")]
    public static IEnumerable<MyType> SelectFiltered(Guid GuidColumn)
    {

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(QueryRepository.SELECT_MyType_GuidColumn, Conn.ConnectionString) { CommandTimeout = 0 };

        command.Parameters.Add("@GuidColumn", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = GuidColumn;

        return new List<MyType>().FromCommand(command);

    }

    #endregion Select Block

}
```

Comment: Where is `Conn` coming from?

Comment: Conn is a class file containing methods that extract and return a `SqlConnection` object. `ConnectionString` is an alias for one of the many methods, normally it is named after the data base.

Comment: Why not just use Linq-To-SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: The method I have been asked to use follows this pattern, though the way it was shown had me explicitly setting each SQL column to a property. The reasoning is that it affords us more low level control over our queries and data layer. Though I would rather not have to explicitly state and cast everything, so that's where this comes in.

Comment: @E-French But are you properly disposing of that `SqlConnection`? Because you don't seem to be doing that for the `SqlCommand`, and both of these would be red flags in a code review.

Comment: @BCdotWEB `Using` should be disposing of those things for me. After running a stress test where many connections are opened consecutively the maximum connections to my database never exceeded one. I may be missing something though.
http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never using `b` in the method. Why make it an extension method if you are going to completely ignore the first argument? In order to use this code, you need to create a new instance that is immediately thrown away. That is unneeded waste.

Instead, you can just specify the generic type in the function call.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FromCommand<T>(SqlCommand command)
{
    // ...
}

[Description("Selects and returns all rows.")]
public static IEnumerable<MyType> SelectAll()
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(QueryRepository.SELECT_MyType_ALL, Conn.ConnectionString) { CommandTimeout = 0 };

    return FromCommand<MyType>(command);
}
```

---

The expression that assigns to `properties` is over 100 characters. That doesn't count the indentation or the variable declaration. That is going to be hard to follow. I suggest that you extract the lambda being passed to `Where()` into a static function with a descriptive name. That way I don't need to think about what is being filtered out.

---

You are adding extra blank lines after opening curly brackets and before some closing curly brackets. This is just inflating the file size and not helping readability.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. You are not disposing the `SqlCommand`.

Comment: @t3chb0t Very good point, I was focused on the extension method issue and missed that one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of caching reflection bits to aid in speed of subsequent access:

```
private static readonly IDictionary<Type, IList<PropertyInfo>> propertyMap =
    new Dictionary<Type, IList<PropertyInfo>>();

public static IEnumerable<T> FromCommand<T>(this IEnumerable<T> b, SqlCommand command)
{

    using (command.Connection)
    {

        command.Connection.Open();

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            var readerColumns = new HashSet<string>(Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName));
            IList<PropertyInfo> properties;

            lock (propertyMap)
            {
                if (!propertyMap.TryGetValue(type, out properties))
                {
                    properties = type.GetProperties().Where(o => o.IsDefined(typeof(SQLColumn)) && readerColumns.Contains(o.Name)).ToList();
                    propertyMap[type] = properties;
                }
            }

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                var OUTPUT = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

                foreach (var item in properties)
                {
                    item.SetValue(OUTPUT, reader[item.Name] is DBNull ? null : reader[item.Name]);
                }

                yield return OUTPUT;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, I honestly never even thought about locking those down because the types never really get too large. ms are ms though, and every one counts!